# Office 365 - download office to local Computer

Tags: office365

Hi guys i am in my 1st IT job,

So office 365 allows you to download the office 2016 and install it locally to your machine.

Will that locally installed office be updated automatically when there are new updates?

The online office will be auto updated right ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You already have a few questions, so hopefully, you'll be getting a lot of use from the site, and maybe answering some questions, too, where you can.  Click the question mark in the top bar and take the quick site tour.  There's also some good general help to get you up to speed quickly.  BTW, feedback is important; voting on posts helps identify for other readers what is useful and not so useful, and you should soon have enough rep to vote (votes are the main way people build reputation and gain privileges).   (cont'd)

Comment: Accepting answers on your own questions helps to identify proven solutions, and also awards a little rep.  Use it for the answer most useful to yourself that solves your problem (you can accept answers even at 1 rep).  Being responsive to posters on your own questions will encourage answers on your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Office 365 ProPlus can get updates automatically from Internet by default.

For example, if your users install Office 365 ProPlus themselves from the Office 365 portal, Office 365 ProPlus is configured to get updates automatically from the Internet. No additional user or administrative configuration is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The standard 'installer' that you receive from the Microsoft site is small and performs as a downloader/installer - it does not include all of the installed files.  When you perform an installation it then retrieves the necessary, current, files from Microsoft's site - so it is always up-to-date.

Any PCs installed in this manner will automatically get updates as Microsoft makes them available.

You *can* have a fully local copy of the installation files - there are [detailed instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/deploy-office-365-proplus-from-a-local-source) on how to do that if you wish.  (Haven't ever tried this method, and don't believe it's particularly common)

Comment: Deploying from a local source is quite common, especially in environments with many users where you don't want multiple GB downloaded every time a new install is needed.

Answer (score 0):

We have remote properties (hotels) that have very slow/limited bandwidth where this could take up to 3 hrs per computer, so not ideal.  In this case, we download the Office Deployment Tool [link here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to download the offline installation files.  We either copy them to disc or USB, and send them to the locations to load on their local server for all the workstations to access.

You'll need the Microsoft Office Deployment Tool from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117).  Put that into a directory somewhere, example:  `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Office2016`

NOTE:  All of your files should be in the same directory as the Office Deployment Tool files, so the two XMLs listed below as well.

My downloadconfig.xml to download the Office 2016 32-bit offline installer files:

```
<Configuration>

  <Add OfficeClientEdition="32" Channel="Monthly">
    <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
    <Product ID="VisioProRetail">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
</Configuration>
```

To start the download of the offline files for Office 2016, create a directory (I create one called Office2016 on my Desktop), CD into that directory:

```
cd 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Office2016'
```

Then to start the download I run:

```
setup.exe /download downloadconfig.xml
```

I also setup the configuration file using [this](https://officedev.github.io/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/XmlEditor.html) site to create the XML code for it.  Configuration I use in a file called installconfig.xml is:

```
<Configuration>
    <Add OfficeClientEdition="32" Channel="Monthly">
        <Product ID="O365ProPlusRetail">
            <Language ID="en-us"/>
        </Product>
    </Add>
    <Updates Enabled="TRUE" Channel="Monthly"/>
    <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE"/>
    <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="FALSE"/>
    <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0"/>
    <Property Name="PinIconsToTaskbar" Value="TRUE"/>
</Configuration>
```

To install from a Command Prompt as Administrator I run:

CD to location of Office 2016 folder on the local computer (where ever you've copied it to or if it lives on a network drive):

```
cd 'C:\Office2016'

setup.exe /configure installconfig.xml
```

NOTE:  You will want to run updates on Office 2016 after install, and may periodically re-download your installer files as they will be updated over time as updates come out.  Doing this will eliminate the number of Office Updates you may have to install if your offline installer files are older.  I usually check this every couple of months.